# Makefile.win da erro ao compilar o projeto

Tags: c++, dev-c++

O arquivo [makefile.win](http://pastebin.com/W0L7kxVa) da um erro ao tentar compilar meu projeto. Aparece um aviso pedindo para recarregar o arquivo, após aperta YES e tentar compilar novamente ele aparece de novo o mesmo aviso(um loop infinito);

Linha do erro:

```
$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

Aviso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que acontece se você apertar "No"? E se você tentar compilar por linha de comando?

Comment: Não acontece nada, caso eu tente compilar de novo ele da o aviso novamente.